# Fibonacci word via recursion in java using string

Tags: java

I have only started writing in java and wrote this program:

```
public class FibonacciWord{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length < 3) System.exit(1);
        int N=Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.println(fibonacci(N,args[0],args[1]));
    }
}

public String fibonacci(int N, String a, String b){
    if (N==0) return a;
    return fibonacci(N-1,a+b,a);
}
```

And then I try to compile it gives a number of errors, the first is:

```
FibonacciWord.java:9 : error: class, interface, or enum expected 
public String fibonacci(int N, String a, String b){
       ^
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: You declaring the method fibonacci outside of your class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declaring the method "fibonacci" outside of your class.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is not in a class. It should be like this:

```
public class FibonacciWord{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length < 3) System.exit(1);
        int N=Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.println(fibonacci(N,args[0],args[1]));
    }

    public String fibonacci(int N, String a, String b){
        if (N==0) return a;
        return fibonacci(N-1,a+b,a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put your method inside the class:

```
public class FibonacciWord{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length < 3) System.exit(1);
        int N=Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.println(fibonacci(N,args[0],args[1]));
    }

    public static String fibonacci(int N, String a, String b){
        if (N==0) return a;
        return fibonacci(N-1,a+b,a);
    }
}
```

And to make it work you should make it `static`. Or you can create new `FibonacciWord` object and call this method from it, like so inside `main`:

```
FibonacciWord solution = new FibonacciWord();
solution.fibonacci(N,args[0],args[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You method is outside the Main class, place it inside.

You have to make it `static` in order to call it from the main method.

```
public class FibonacciWord{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length < 3) System.exit(1);
        int N=Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.println(fibonacci(N,args[0],args[1]));
    }

    public static String fibonacci(int N, String a, String b){
        if (N==0) return a;
        return fibonacci(N-1,a+b,a);
    }
}
```